# python count number of triple-repeats in one field of a list of tuples

Tags: python, list, list-comprehension

I have list of list with names, first and last names.

How do I get the count of last names greater than 3.

```
import collections

names = [['Fiona','Murray'],
['Diane','Springer'],
['Dylan','Oliver'],
['Alison','McDonald'],
['Sophie','Peters'],
['Kevin','Davidson'],
['David','Marshall'],
['Jake','Lewis'],
['Thomas','Burgess'],
['Fiona','Murray'],
['Fiona','Murray'],
['Fiona','Murray'],
['Fiona','Murray'],
['Dylan','Oliver'],
['Dylan','Oliver'] ]

lst1 = [(a,b) for (a,b) in collections.Counter(map(tuple,names)).iteritems()]
```

I tried list comprehension but unable to get the last names greater than 3.

Comment: You want to get the last names with greater than 3 count?

Comment: Yes, Anand. That is what I am looking for.

Comment: your counter is counting full names, not last names. you need to start by isolating the last names

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A more functional programming approach.

```
from collections import Counter
from operator import itemgetter
from itertools import imap

[(name, count) for name, count in Counter(imap(itemgetter(1), names)).iteritems() if count > 3]
```

Comment: Thanks for the approach.

Comment: I don't really see the use of `imap` when `(name[1] for name in names)` does the same thing and is clearer to read

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter):

```
from collections import Counter
counter = Counter([item[1] for item in names])
keys = [key for key, value in counter.items() if value > 3]
print(keys)
```

will print:

```
['Murray']
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you are using the complete tuple (both first name and last name) in the `collections.Counter` , for what you want, you need to use only the second element of each inner list (not the complete inner list converted to tuple) .

Secondly, in the list comprehension there is no condition that is checking for the count to be greater than 3. You should check if `b` is greater than 3 or not.

Example -

```
>>> lst1 = [(a,b) for (a,b) in collections.Counter([a[1] for a in names]).iteritems() if b > 3]
>>> lst1
[('Murray', 5)]
```

Comment: Makes sense. Thanks for clarifying it.

Answer (score 1):

```
lst1=[entry[0] for entry in collections.Counter(map(tuple,names)).iteritems() if entry[1]>3]
```

and for the count, just put len() in front of it.

Comment: This is exactly I was looking for.